# How to insert all rows from JSON_Object to SQL Table using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am new to Python and APIs. Data is a result of API response.

I have a json_object like below.

```
json_object = json.dumps(data,indent=2)
```

which has data like below. I successfully connected to SQL server localhost using pymssql but I need help in extracting all the rows from this json to sql table (Table_A).

I tried referring various posts but they are selecting the individual columns from json. But I may have 20 plus columns from json result. So assume that I have a table with all those 20+ columns (Table A).

How to send this data to ms sql server?

```
[
  {
    "Key": "ITSAMPLE-8142",
    "Summary": "Test Issue,Data.Analystz.111,Data.Analystz.111",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  {
    "Key": "ITSAMPLE-8141",
    "Summary": "Test Issue,Data.Analystz.111,Data.Analystz.111",
    "Status": "Open"
  }
]
```

Comment: Send it as a string and do the JSON handling inside SQL server?

Comment: Can you please help me with a code. I am leterally struggling and not able to do this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16